# make graphql mutation return multiple types

Tags: typescript, express, graphql, sequelize.js, express-graphql

i'm working on creating mutations for a project i'm working on but stuck on the resolver returns, i won't to handle the errors while i'm at it as well by sending back messages for notifications to make it user friendly, but let's say my mutation is UPDATE_USER and it should also return the updated user instance, how can i set my mutation to double returns if possible?

that's how it looks

```
export const UPDATE_USER = {
    type: UserType,
    args: {
        user_id: {type: GraphQLString}!,
        first_name: {type: GraphQLString}!,
        last_name: {type: GraphQLString},
```

but i want something like this incase there's no user like the update failed for some reason

```
export const UPDATE_USER = {
    type: UserType|| MessageType,
    args: {
        user_id: {type: GraphQLString}!,
        first_name: {type: GraphQLString}!,
        last_name: {type: GraphQLString},
```

but i can't find a way to make it work

Comment: Why not just customize the error you throw instead of extending the return type?

Answer (score 0):

In GraphQL, you can't directly return multiple types from a single field, but you can create a wrapper type that can contain either the user or the error message. This is often called a "union type" or an "interface type".

Here's how you can define a union type for this purpose:

```
union UserResult = UserType | MessageType
```

Then, you can use this `UserResult` type in your `UPDATE_USER` mutation:

```
export const UPDATE_USER = {
    type: UserResult,
    args: {
        user_id: {type: GraphQLString},
        first_name: {type: GraphQLString},
        last_name: {type: GraphQLString},
    },
    resolve: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
        // Your logic here
        if (errorCondition) {
            return {
                __typename: "MessageType",
                message: "An error occurred",
            };
        } else {
            return {
                __typename: "UserType",
                // ...user fields
            };
        }
    }
};
```

In the resolver, you can specify which type you are returning by setting the `__typename` field. The client can then use inline fragments to handle the different types:

```
mutation {
  updateUser(user_id: "1", first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe") {
    __typename
    ... on UserType {
      user_id
      first_name
      last_name
    }
    ... on MessageType {
      message
    }
  }
}
```

This way, you can return either a `UserType` or a `MessageType` from your `UPDATE_USER` mutation, and the client can handle both cases.

Comment: to avoid making union types for every model I have, I made a kinda ghetto fix, by creating a notification/message typeDef, and referencing it in each type i have, which makes me return the data and also the response i want for notifications